# Pretty print XML in Chrome Developer Tool

Tags: xml, google-chrome-devtools, pretty-print

I can't figure out how to pretty print XML in Chrome Developer Tools. Both my "Preview" and "Response" tab under the "Network" panels shows the XML in its raw form.

I'm using Chrome 26.0.1410.65 (latest as of writing) and OS X 10.8.3 (also latest).

[image]
[image]

Here is the header information if it helps:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JavaScript or jQuery, just use `console.log()` and the xml will be pretty printed.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed with the new version of chrome (Version 42.0.2311.90 m). Finally :)